# Use custom Connector function in Visual Studio (when using the Power Query SDK)

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, sdk, powerquery

This is one for the experts. I would like to access my custom connector functions when querying / coding Power M in Visual Studio (with the Power Query SDK). I added my connector file to the

[Documents]\Power BI Desktop\Custom Connectors

folder. And my connector and functions are available in Power BI (Power Query):

[image: Shared functions in Power BI]

Yet, when I access my shared functions within Visual Studio, my extension is not listed?

[image: Shared functions in Visual Studio]

Does anybody have a solution for this?

Kind regards,

Steve.

Answer (score 0):

### Try

```
let 
    x = SomethingSuperExpensive(),
    y = #shared
in 
   y
```

### If your query is

```
let 
    x = SomethingSuperExpensive(),
    y = ...,
in 
   [ Stuff = 10 ]
```

It will lazily evaluate it, x and y are never evaluated. That's probably happening.